# Two network access

Tags: networking

I have the following conf:

A Win XP machine connected to a network having the following settings:

```
ip:      192.168.20.50
subnet:  255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.20.1
```

And I use this network to connect to an application for warehousing storage & logistics (a local network that has no internet access). I do not have access to change any settings on that network, I am just provided with a link and an application that specifically requires me to have those settings.

Now on the same computer I would like to have both access to this network and internet access. I can get internet access thru my router having the following settings:

```
ip:      192.168.1.2
subnet:  255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

So I have purchased an additional network card, and one is used for the local network, and the other for internet access.

My problem is that I cannot have parallel internet and access to the local application. Right now I disable one network adapter, and so on. But it is not practical.

Is there a way so that I can have both simultaneous access?

All help is appriciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that the link to the warehousing software is on the 192.168.20.0/24 network?  If so, you don't need a default gateway on that network so remove the default gateway from the 192.168.20.50 network adapter.

It's likely that the metric is lower for the warehousing network's gateway so all your non-local traffic is going out through the 192.168.20.1 gateway, which won't work, as there's no Internet to route to.

If you can't change the network adapter settings, you'll have to run `route` commands to temporarily make changes to your routing table to direct non-local traffic (destination IPs that are not on either the 192.168.20.0/24 or 192.168.1.0/24) to the 192.168.1.1 default gateway.  Not entirely sure if the `route` command can be executing by users that do not have local administrator rights, however.

Answer (score 1):

I found an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1054825.html) on the that explain your problem. You'll only have to edit your different interface with their own network. Windows should adapt his routing information.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you network looks like logically

```
_____
NIC  |--192.168.20.0 /24--Server
     |
PC   |
     |
NIC  |--192.168.1.0 /24--Router--Internet
------
```

then, as has been suggested, configure the 192.168.20.0 /24 interface without a default gateway and
configure the 192.168.1.0 /24 interface with a default gateway of 192.168.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default gateway 192.168.20.0/24 network. If there are other subnets within that network that you need to access then create routes for just those networks.

For example 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0 nexthop 192.168.20.1